# Xamarin, графическая няшность

Tags: c#, xamarin, design

Приветсвую. 
Я изучаю Xamarin и мне интересно как сделать так, чтобы на кнопке были блики, полутона и тд? Стандартных средств не хватает или Я в них плохо разбираюсь, прошу посоветовать библеотеку но с хорошей инструкцией )

Comment: А блендовские инструменты в студии не работают?

Comment: "блендовские инструменты" Что  это такое?

Comment: Бленд - теперь входит в состав студии, служит для разработки и визуализации интерфейсов. Детали лучше спросить у Гугла,  искать: blend microsoft

Comment: Попробовал blend- не поддерживает проекты xamarin.А если пытаешься сделать кнопку в blend и пихать в xamarin- , логично, что xamarin ругается .

Comment: Странно, на выходе же получается xaml описание, оно одинаковое, за исключением ссылок на домены, что где искать. Но это легко настроить руками.

Comment: Стандартными средствами это невозможно добиться, потому что каждая из платформ(Android, iOS, UWP и тд) реализуют их по-разному. Вам надо создать собственный пользовательский элемент, а его реализацию визуализации перенести в проекты платформ. Для Xamarin.Forms https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавлю, ещё кое что, к предложенным ответам.  Наткнулся Я случайно на этого мощного Айтишника : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/xamarinforms-custom-button .

Чувак создал свой рендер и свою кнопку на основе имеющихся классов...  Оказывается, так можно. На основе его работы и этих трех статей https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/4.4.php
https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/14.1.php  https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/14.2.php , можно сделать свою кастомизацию для кнопки...

Answer (score 1):

Не работал с ксамарином, но судя по линке: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58597/forms9patch-simplify-multi-device-image-management-in-your-pcl-xamarin-forms-mobile-apps#latest

парень создал собственный контрол кнопки **ImageButton**, у которого можно менять бэкграунд  как через проперти програмно, так и через ксамл.

Здесь же по линке найдешь как нюгет с либой, так и демо-апликуху.

Comment: Там требуется лицуха, чего у бедных студентов нету)))